# how to change the arrow direction in HyperTree in JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit

Tags: javascript, toolkit, infovis

I have the following json for HyperTree

```
var json = {
    "id": "347_0",
    "name": "AAA",
    "children": [{
        "id": "126510_1",
        "name": "BBB",
        "data": {
            "band": "BBB",
            "relation": "Subscriber"
         },
        "children": []
    }, {...
```

After I change the line type to arrow, there is an arrow pointing from AAA -> BBB. But I want the arrow direction is from BBB -> AAA.

Do you have any idea on how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loading a json data in which A is in the "children" array of B i.e. A is the child of B ?

I have not tested it.....just an idea with assumption that arrow always points from parent to child.
             Parent ----------->  Child

Comment: Or another way of question is: whether json in Hypertree support multiple parent nodes or not. Thanks. Because in my case, A is a central node, some nodes are parents of A and some nodes are children of A.

Comment: That is a totally different question. Your question was about making B point to A, not about a central node having multiple parents and children.